# Can I let Core Data use an already created sql database

Tags: objective-c

I have a mosques database that has 1000 items ..

I want to use Core Data approach in accessing my database ..

I have already tried the SQLite approach to create the database 
where I have a text Pad file with all data seperated by tabs 
and then Import the data from txt file to sql file ..

Now this works fine ..

I want to know how can I import data from my SQL file to the newly created Core Data Project

Shall I add SQL file to resources ??
Copy it or not ??

I have looked at CoreDataBooks example but I think I'm missing something

I want to know the exact way for adding an SQL file to the resources of a Core Data Project ..

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

You should regard the fact that Core Data uses SQLite as the format to save the file as an implementation detail, not to be used directly <strike>unless you really, really, really need to do that</strike>. For example, you can't expect Core Data to work alright if you also directly writes on to the SQLite file.

Instead, read the Core Data documentation, and import the data directly from the tab-separated text file to the Core Data context, and let the Core Data save it to the file. Yes it does use SQLite behind the scenes, but it's better for you to forget that fact.

Comment: Thank you Yuji, ok then .. Is this the way of importing the tab-seperated text file to Core Data ( http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/08/core-data-starting-data.html ) or is there a better way ?? Sorry but I'm really new to Obj-C ..

Comment: +1 except that you never "really really really need" to use the sqlite directly.  It's schema is a custom format explicitly chosen by the framework, and even mucking around with the data it contains is a bad idea.

Comment: You're perfectly right, Dave. I meant in the way that you should never use in a production code... it's always to fun to directly open it using SQLite to see what Apple does.

Comment: @Sara There's no easy, quick way to learn Core Data, especially if you're new to Objective-C. It's because it uses a lot of Objective-C/Cocoa conventions, and also because it's a big framework. You should resist the urge to start coding on the day one. So, stop googling for a short tutorial. Rather, you should start by reading the standard documents (e.g. Apple's Cocoa fundamentals and iPhone Core Data tutorial. Go to developer.apple.com; you can find them there.) A week spent on learning the basics will save you months later.

Answer (score 0):

Yuji and Dave DeLong are right on both accounts, however I feel like I should add that just because you can't realistically feed CoreData a pre-populated SQLite file doesn't mean you can't bootstrap your CoreData store from a SQLite file (or a text file or anything else.) It just means that you have to do the work yourself.

For instance, you could include your pre-populated SQLite file (with it's own, non-CoreData schema, etc) as a resource in the project. Then when your app starts up, if it sees that the CoreData store is empty, you can use the SQLite API directly to open/query your bootstrapping database and translate the results into operations that generate the desired object graph in CoreData.  The next time the app starts up, the CoreData object graph will be populated, and you won't have to do it again.

The take away here is that while it's not "free," it's not "impossible."  Many, many apps include built-in CoreData repositories that contain data.  That data had to be bootstrapped from somewhere, right?